# Elasticsearch external document "terms" search query not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to do "terms" query using document on other index as the source for search string. However I am not getting any hits.

-- index the information for user with id 2, specifically, its followers

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/users/user/2 -d '{
   "followers" : ["1", "3"]
}'
```

-- index a tweet, from user with id 2

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/tweets/tweet/1 -d '{
   "user" : "2"
}'
```

-- search on all the tweets that match the followers of user 2

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/tweets/_search -d '{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "terms" : {
          "user" : {
            "index" : "users",
            "type" : "user",
            "id" : "2",
            "path" : "followers"
          },
          "_cache_key" : "user_2_friends"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Result: 0 hits.

However if I change the query to:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "terms" : {
          "user" : [2]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Above query gives me 1 hit, which means there is some problem with the external search query.

Details:
http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html

I am using ES version: 1.5.2 also tried the query in 1.4.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query :

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "terms" : {
          "user" : [1,3]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

is the same as

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "terms" : {
          "user" : {
            "index" : "users",
            "type" : "user",
            "id" : "2",
            "path" : "followers"
          },
          "_cache_key" : "user_2_friends"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and not the one you have in the OP. 
You probably did not index tweets for user 1 and 3.

Comment: Thanks for the response, now that seems so obvious. I was blindly believing the documented exampled on elastic.co